# Smallest Word Search Puzzle

Tags: code-golf, word-search

A word search is a matrix of letters as defined in [Word Search Puzzle Generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47253/61384). For a word search to contain a word, it means that that word appears somewhere in the matrix horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

Your task is to write a program that takes a list of strings and outputs the dimensions of the smallest-area word search that contains those strings.

### Specifications

- You can assume the word search and the input strings consist of only lowercase ASCII letters.
- You can output the dimensions in either order (`y x` instead of `x y`) because it doesn't matter to the word search.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid solution (in bytes) wins.

### Test Cases

```
word                     -> 4 1
hello, e                 -> 5 1
hello, f                 -> 6 1
small, llama             -> 8 1
words, other             -> 5 2
words, order, about, orb -> 5 3
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that makes a meaningful difference? Do you have any reason to suspect any algorithm that would be competitive here and not if you had to print it?

Comment: Actually, there's a fairly major difference: that challenge asked for squares, this one for rectangles, and that may well make a large difference. If not for that, though, I'd call it a duplicate; the difference in output format might change which language wins, but it's unlikely to change the non-output part of the algorithms.

Comment: None of the test cases include diagonals, you should probably add one for that.

Comment: Wouldn't `hello, f` be 6 1 ? 6x1 is smaller than 5x2

Comment: @SLC Yes, edited.

Comment: This is till a dupe as trivial edits to get an answer

Comment: @ChristopherPeart as ais523 pointed out, that challenged asked strictly for square matrices, while this one asked for arbitrary rectangles, so algorithms that worked for that challenge might not work for this one. That said, I suppose it's similar enough that it might be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: ³L jelly 2 bytes words must just be put in as one long word. :P