# Word Search Helper

Tags: code-golf, string, grid, word-search

I've been doing word searches recently, and I thought it would be *so* much easier if all of the words read left-to-right. But rewriting all the lines takes a lot of effort! So I'm enlisting code golfers to help.

<sup><sub><sup>(Disclaimer: The above story may or may not be remotely accurate.)</sup></sub></sup>

Your code will take a rectangular grid and output all of the lines through it in both directions.

The output must contain all 8 rotations of the grid (cardinals and main diagonals), 'read off' top to bottom, left to right. (This means that every "row" will be duplicated - once forwards, and once backwards.)

The line divisions can either be a space or a line break. If you choose spaces, the grid rotation divisions must be line breaks; otherwise, the grid rotation divisions must be two line breaks.

**Example input** (taken as an array of characters, multiline string, or other reasonable format)

```
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
PQRST
```

**Example output** (using the first option for divisions)

```
ABCDE FGHIJ KLMNO PQRST
E DJ CIO BHNT AGMS FLR KQ P
EJOT DINS CHMR BGLQ AFKP
T OS JNR EIMQ DHLP CGK BF A
TSRQP ONMLK JIHGF EDBCA
P QK RLF SMGA TNHB OIC JD E
PKFA QLGB RMHC SNID TOJE
A FB KGC PLHD QMIE RNJ SO T
```

The order of the rotations "read off" does not matter as long as all eight cardinals and primary intercardinals are done once.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins. Standard loopholes apply.

Comment: Does the grid only contain uppercase letters or can it be the whole printable ASCII?

Comment: Almost duplicate (without the diagonals) http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37940/word-search-puzzle

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: No, not really - this one doesn't ask you to find any words at all.

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3, 181 bytes

```
def f(s):
 for k in [1,0]*4:
  b=list(zip(*[([' ']*(len(s)-1-n)*k+list(i)+[' ']*n*k)[::-1] for n,i in enumerate(s)]))
  print([' '.join(i).replace(' ','') for i in b])
  if k==0:s=b
```

### Explanation

```
def f(s):
 for k in [0]*4:                  # loop 4 times, we don't need the index so [0]*4 is shorter than range(4)
  l=len(s)-1                      # number of line

  # rotation of 45°
  a=[(['.']*(l-n)+list(i)+['.']*n)[::-1] for n,i in enumerate(s)]
  # tranform matrice :
  #  ABC      ..ABC      CBA..
  #  DEF  --> .DEF.  --> .FED.
  #  GHI      GHI..      ..IHG
  b=list(zip(*a))                 # transpose 
  #  CBA..      C..
  #  .FED.  --> BF.
  #  ..IHG      AEI
  #             .DH
  #             ..G
  print(' '.join(''.join(i).replace('.','') for i in b))

  # rotation of 90°
  a=[(list(i))[::-1] for n,i in enumerate(s)]
  # tranform matrice :
  #  ABC      CBA
  #  DEF  --> FED
  #  GHI      IHG
  b=list(zip(*a))                 # transpose 
  #  CBA       CFI
  #  FED   --> BEH
  #  IHG       ADG
  print(' '.join(''.join(i) for i in b))
  s=b
```

### Results

```
>>> f(['ABCDE','FGHIJ','KLMNO','PQRST'])
['E', 'DJ', 'CIO', 'BHNT', 'AGMS', 'FLR', 'KQ', 'P']
['EJOT', 'DINS', 'CHMR', 'BGLQ', 'AFKP']
['T', 'OS', 'JNR', 'EIMQ', 'DHLP', 'CGK', 'BF', 'A']
['TSRQP', 'ONMLK', 'JIHGF', 'EDCBA']
['P', 'QK', 'RLF', 'SMGA', 'TNHB', 'OIC', 'JD', 'E']
['PKFA', 'QLGB', 'RMHC', 'SNID', 'TOJE']
['A', 'FB', 'KGC', 'PLHD', 'QMIE', 'RNJ', 'SO', 'T']
['ABCDE', 'FGHIJ', 'KLMNO', 'PQRST']

>>> f(['ABCDEF','GHIJKL','MNOPQR','STUVWX'])
['F', 'EL', 'DKR', 'CJQX', 'BIPW', 'AHOV', 'GNU', 'MT', 'S']
['FLRX', 'EKQW', 'DJPV', 'CIOU', 'BHNT', 'AGMS']
['X', 'RW', 'LQV', 'FKPU', 'EJOT', 'DINS', 'CHM', 'BG', 'A']
['XWVUTS', 'RQPONM', 'LKJIHG', 'FEDCBA']
['S', 'TM', 'UNG', 'VOHA', 'WPIB', 'XQJC', 'RKD', 'LE', 'F']
['SMGA', 'TNHB', 'UOIC', 'VPJD', 'WQKE', 'XRLF']
['A', 'GB', 'MHC', 'SNID', 'TOJE', 'UPKF', 'VQL', 'WR', 'X']
['ABCDEF', 'GHIJKL', 'MNOPQR', 'STUVWX']
```

**with a cleaner output (189 bytes)**

```
j=' '.join
def f(s):
 for k in [1,0]*4:
  b=list(zip(*[([' ']*(len(s)-1-n)*k+list(i)+[' ']*n*k)[::-1] for n,i in enumerate(s)]))
  print(j(j(i).replace(' ','') for i in b))
  if k==0:s=b
```

.

```
>>> f(['ABCDE','FGHIJ','KLMNO','PQRST'])
E DJ CIO BHNT AGMS FLR KQ P
EJOT DINS CHMR BGLQ AFKP
T OS JNR EIMQ DHLP CGK BF A
TSRQP ONMLK JIHGF EDCBA
P QK RLF SMGA TNHB OIC JD E
PKFA QLGB RMHC SNID TOJE
A FB KGC PLHD QMIE RNJ SO T
ABCDE FGHIJ KLMNO PQRST
```

Comment: How do you tranforme a matrix? (code block 2)

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy I added one more step in explanations

Comment: I'm pretty sure tranforme isn't a word. (transform?)

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy ^^ ok, i think that was obvious that English is not my native language

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 40 bytes

```
t!tP!tP!GXKZyqXI"IZ}w_w2$:"K@2$Xd!]K!XKx
```

Input is a 2D char array in Matlab notation:

```
['ABCDE'; 'FGHIJ'; 'KLMNO'; 'PQRST']
```

The output contains each "word" on a separate line.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dCF0UCF0UCFHWEtaeXFYSSJJWn13X3cyJDoiS0AyJFhkIV1LIVhLeA&input=WydBQkNERSc7ICdGR0hJSic7ICdLTE1OTyc7ICdQUVJTVCdd)

```
t          % input 2D char array. Duplicate. The original copy will produce
           % the words left to right when displayed
!          % transpose. This will produce the words up to down
tP!        % duplicate, flip upside down, transpose. This will produce the
           % words right to left
tP!        % Same. This will produce the words down to up 
GXK        % push input again. Copy to clipboard K
Zy         % get size (length-2 vector; [4 5] in the example)
q          % decrement by 1 (gives  [3 4] in the example)
XI         % copy to clipboard I
"          % loop: do this twice, consuming the decremented length-2 vector
  I        %   push decremented size vector again
  Z}       %   split into its two elements (pushes 3 and 4 in the example)
  w_w      %   swap, negave, swap (results in -3, 4 in the example)
  2$:      %   binary range: indices of diagonals  ([-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4]
           %   in the first iteration in the example, [-4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3]
           %   in the second)
  "        %   for each
    K      %     push input (first iteration) or its tranposed version (second)
    @      %     push index of diagonal
    2$Xd!  %     extract that diagonal as a row vector
  ]        %   end for each
  K!XKx    %   update clipboard K with transposed version for next iteration
           % end loop. Display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
4F=íøDεÐS0:«NFÁ}}øí0мõK,
```

Input as a list of lines; outputs as list of strings as well, each on a separated newline to STDOUT.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fxM328NrDO1zObT08IdjA6tBqP7fDjbW1h3ccXmtwYc/hrd46//9HKzk6Obu4Kukoubl7eHoBaW8fXz9/IB0QGBQcohQLAA)

**Explanation:**

Unfortunately 05AB1E doesn't have an (anti-)diagonals builtin, so 17 of the bytes are to accomplish that in a similar matter as [my 05AB1E answer for the *Diamondize a Matrix* challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203697/52210).

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, since it can zip/transpose on a list of strings, whereas the new 05AB1E version requires it to be a character-matrix.

```python
4F             # Loop 4 times:
  =            #  Print the current list with trailing newline (without popping)
               #  (which will use the implicit input-list in the first iteration)
   íø          #  Rotate once 90 degrees clockwise:
   í           #   Reverse each line
    ø          #   Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
     D         #  Duplicate this rotated grid
      ε        #  Map over each line:
       ÐS0:«   #   Append the length amount of "0"s:
       Ð       #    Triplicate the string
        S      #    Convert the top copy to a list of characters
         0:    #    Replace all these characters in another copy to "0"
           NF  #   Loop the (0-based) map-index amount of times:
             Á #    Rotate once towards the right
            }  #   Close the loop
      }        #  Close the map
       øí      #  Rotate once 90 degrees counterclockwise
         0м    #  Remove all "0"s from each inner string
           õK  #  Remove potential empty strings
             , #  Pop and output this list of diagonals with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
KṄḲ
ZUÇƊƬŒDÇ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUsAtP9qZWxsef//S@G5hOG4sgpaVcOHxorGrMWSRMOH4oKs/@G7tMOHxZLhuZjIp@KAnOKAnf//QUJDREUKRkdISUoKS0xNTk8KUFFSU1Q)

Ok, so this is fairly liberal with I/O, but I don't think any of the assumptions are a major issue:

- The output for each row is in a different order than specified in the question. Because of

  > The order of the rotations "read off" does not matter as long as all eight cardinals and primary intercardinals are done once.

  I assumed this was OK
- The output for half of the diagonals is in "reverse" order (i.e. the output includes `PLHD` instead of `DHLP`)

  If this isn't ok, then [+3 bytes](https://tio.run/##AU8AsP9qZWxsef//S@G5hOG4sgpaVcOHxorGrMWSRFXDkGXDh@KCrP/hu7TDh8WS4bmYyKfigJzigJ3//0FCQ0RFCkZHSElKCktMTU5PClBRUlNU)
- This is a "link" in Jelly, which is Jelly's version of a function. This takes takes input via ARGV and outputs to STDIN rather than "returning" a value. The `ȧ“”` in the Footer suppresses Jelly implicitly outputting the return value for the link
- This takes input as a matrix of characters. This seems to be allowed by

  > Example input (taken as an array of characters, multiline string, or other reasonable format)

---

### How it works

```
KṄḲ - Helper link. Takes a string S on the left
K   - Join S by spaces
 Ṅ  - Print S
  Ḳ - Split S on spaces

ZUÇƊƬŒDÇ€ - Main link. Takes a matrix M of characters
   Ɗ      - Group the previous 3 links into a monad f(M):
Z         -   Transpose
 U        -   Reverse
  Ç       -   Call the helper link
    Ƭ     - Yield [f(M), f(f(M)), f(f(f(M))), f(f(f(f(M))) = M]
            This outputs and returns all rotations of M
     ŒD   - Get the diagonals of each
       Ç€ - Call the helper link on each diagonal
```

Comment: "(i.e. the output includes PLHD instead of DHLP)" it correctly includes both, as per spec

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 135 bytes

```javascript
f=(s,n=8)=>n?[s.flatMap(t=>t.join``||[]),...f([...Array(L=(s+0).length)].map((_,y,p)=>p.map((_,x)=>(s[y+x-L>>1]||0)[(x-y)/2])),n-1)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5NDoIwFISPQ18oFVwZEzDu8QRNI5V/LG2ljYGEu9dnjJuZzOKbmUm@pauX0fpEm6YNocuJozo/QV7oC3esU9LfpCU@LzybzKirat@5AMoY6whHvS6L3EiJXJwCU63u/QCCzQiRO92oxSr7jysG4vgWr0lZFJnY9xQ4WZMNDkcBQHWSgThzEWqjnVEtU6YnuBPJR920EY26fhgn9KeatUG3r8X56DeHH7@HPBZB@AA)

Slow. Complexity O(n^256) [Proof that the rotation work](https://tio.run/##NY5LDoMgGISPA0Sg2pVpok339gSEVOrbIlAhjSbe3f6m6WYms5hvZlQf5at5cIEZWzf73mbYU5OlJMvNVVTWeKsbrm2HPW@1CnflcMjywEc7mLLcNiEJoZzzFgvQ2zyrFRcAiWLCdWO60EcpkXyCHn7QlTogu39cIGAv1mhhRZ4ncttiIvDCVnI6H1zDEiIvQu5AR@pZ1Q2iqO36YQR/6clYcPeefUC/Cbh23AhQ3r8) [Fast run](https://tio.run/##PY9BbsMgEEX3OYV3BsWmTldVI6iqbNMTINQQBxxcDC6QyKju2V3s1t3MaJj//zxafue@dqoPpbEXMR2wvJk6KGuALwz82mSZz3DmkVQ6CAcGTAbUWmVOJ7hPyzt32XkW0IqhjvcAvBcKYuKRt50AEZNIFYOL1olwcyaTwC/KgElYY/9c50Wb7u4335PEMwJ@Su/mhSYCzcPb6vtFGEfKYIEQOgCa6qtzPIJj8m0riLQwTbjCf6xY9CmqX8chDcDTuB3KIyE7No4VpGAoI3x4XCDKHWTPlE21Nd5qgbRtgAQ05@f6IvIil81Vtal/6M7Y1PtP50PO1r/NQCEFwekH)