# Zigzagify a Matrix

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix

As part of its compression algorithm, the JPEG standard unrolls a matrix into a vector along antidiagonals of alternating direction:

[image]

Your task is to take a matrix (not necessarily square) and return it in unrolled form. As an example:

```
[1 2 3 4
 5 6 7 8
 9 1 2 3]
```

should yield

```
[1, 2, 5, 9, 6, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 3]
```

### Rules

You may assume that the matrix elements are positive integers less than `10`.

You may write a program or function, taking input via STDIN (or closest alternative), command-line argument or function argument and outputting the result via STDOUT (or closest alternative), function return value or function (out) parameter.

The input matrix may be given in any convenient, unambiguous, nested list or string format, or as a flat list along with both matrix dimensions. (Or, of course, as a matrix type if your language has those.)

The output vector may be in any convenient, unambiguous, flat list or string format.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

### Test Cases

```
[[1]]                                               => [1]
[[1 2] [3 1]]                                       => [1 2 3 1]
[[1 2 3 1]]                                         => [1 2 3 1]
[[1 2 3] [5 6 4] [9 7 8] [1 2 3]]                   => [1 2 5 9 6 3 4 7 1 2 8 3]
[[1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8] [9 1 2 3]]                     => [1 2 5 9 6 3 4 7 1 2 8 3]
[[1 2 6 3 1 2] [5 9 4 7 8 3]]                       => [1 2 5 9 6 3 4 7 1 2 8 3]
[[1 2 5 9 6 3 4 7 1 2 8 3]]                         => [1 2 5 9 6 3 4 7 1 2 8 3]
[[1] [2] [5] [9] [6] [3] [4] [7] [1] [2] [8] [3]]   => [1 2 5 9 6 3 4 7 1 2 8 3]
```

### Related Challenges

- [Reconstruct a zigzagified matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75588/8478) (the somewhat trickier inverse transformation)
- [Rotate the anti-diagonals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63755/8478)

Comment: Can the input be an actual matrix in J? Or would it need to be turned from nested lists into a matrix as part of the function?

Comment: If we take the matrix as a 2D array, may we still take the dimensions as inputs?

Comment: @Gareth yes you can take a matrix type as input.

Comment: @xnor Hmmm, that one's a bit trickier. I feel like taking that amount of redundant information goes a bit into preprocessing the input.

Comment: Can the flat list be in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) if that's the language's native order?

Comment: @DonMuesli sure.

Comment: This link to a question I posted on StackOverflow in the past may also be fruitful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369142/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-zig-zag-ordering-in-matlab.  It was unfortunately linked to another duplicate, but both the question and the duplicate may provide fruitful information on why the zigzag order is important in JPEG compression.

Comment: This [challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75334/49289) is related too

Comment: Are elements strictly positive or can we have some zero ?

Comment: @Erwan strictly positive

Comment: Shouldn't this be "unzigzagify a matrix"? This is making the input less complex then the output...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## J, <strike>31</strike> <strike>30</strike> <strike>14</strike> <strike>12</strike> 11 bytes

```
[:;<@|.`</.
```

<strike>[Ych](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ych_a_fi). Too big.</strike>

Takes a matrix as input.

**Explanation**

J has an advantage here. There's a command called [oblique](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d421.htm) (`/.`) which takes the oblique lines in turn and applies a verb to them. In this case I'm using a gerund to apply two verbs alternately: `<` ([box](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d010.htm)) and `<@|.` ([reverse](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d231.htm) and box). Then it's just a matter of unboxing everything using `;` ([raze](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d330.htm)).

Comment: J is the only language that makes me feel like I need an advanced degree in English to understand it.

Comment: @AlexA. btw, the word "command" should have been "adverb".

Answer (score 13):

## Jelly, <s>24</s> <s>19</s> <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
pS€żị"¥pỤị⁵
```

Takes number of rows, number of columns and a flat list as separate command-line arguments.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=cFPigqzFvOG7iyLCpXDhu6Thu4vigbU&input=&args=NA+Mw+WzEsIDIsIDMsIDUsIDYsIDQsIDksIDcsIDgsIDEsIDIsIDNd)

#### How it works

```
pS€żị"¥pỤị⁵  Main link. Argument: m (rows), n (columns), A (list, flat)

p            Compute the Cartesian product [1, ..., m] × [1, ..., n]. This yields
             the indices of the matrix M, i.e., [[1, 1], [1, 2], ..., [m, n]].
 S€          Compute the sums of all index pairs.
       p     Yield the Cartesian product.
      ¥      Dyadic chain. Arguments: Sums, Cartesian product.
    ị"       For each index pair in the Cartesian product, retrieve the coordinate
             at the index of its sum, i.e., map [i, j] to i if i + j is odd and to
             j if i + j is even.
   ż         Zip the sums with the retrieved indices.
       Ụ     Sort [1, ..., mn] by the corresponding item in the resulting list.
        ị⁵   Retrieve the corresponding items from A.
```

Comment: Tsk. I'm not sure if I can make mine any shorter now. :-S

Comment: That's not to say I won't try though...

Comment: Why hasn't Jelly inherited Oblique yet? May I suggest the APL glyphs `⍁` and `⍂`? Or maybe Scandinavian `ø` and `ǿ`?

Answer (score 11):

### Pyth, <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>21</s> <s>20</s> <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
ssm_W=!Td.T+LaYkQ
```

Alternate 17-byte version: `ssuL_G=!T.T+LaYkQ`

```
                Q  input
           +L      prepend to each subarray...
             aYk   (Y += ''). Y is initialized to [], so this prepends [''] to
                     the first subarray, ['', ''] to the second, etc.
                   ['' 1  2  3  4
                    '' '' 5  6  7  8
                    '' '' '' 9  1  2  3]
         .T        transpose, giving us
                   ['' '' ''
                    1  '' ''
                    2  5  ''
                    3  6  9
                    4  7  1
                    8  2
                    3]
  m_W=!Td          black magic
 s                 join subarrays together
s                  join *everything* on empty string (which means ''s used for
                     padding disappear)
```

Thanks to [@FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman) for a byte, [@Jakube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29577/jakube) for 2 bytes, and [@isaacg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20080/isaacg) for a byte!

Explanation of "black magic" alluded to above: `m_W=!Td` essentially reverses every other subarray. It does this by mapping `_W=!T` over each subarray; `W` is conditional application, so it `_`s (reverses) all subarrays where `=!T` is true. `T` is a variable preinitialized to ten (truthy), and `=!T` means `(T = !T)`. So it toggles the value of a variable that starts out truthy and returns the new value, which means that it will alternate between returning falsy, truthy, falsy, truthy... (credit to Jakube for this idea)

[Test suite here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ssm_W%3D%21Td.T%2BLaYkQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5B1%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B3%2C1%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C1%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B5%2C6%2C4%5D%2C%5B9%2C7%2C8%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C%5B5%2C6%2C7%2C8%5D%2C%5B9%2C1%2C2%2C3%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%2C6%2C3%2C1%2C2%5D%2C%5B5%2C9%2C4%2C7%2C8%2C3%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C2%2C5%2C9%2C6%2C3%2C4%2C7%2C1%2C2%2C8%2C3%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%5D%2C%5B2%5D%2C%5B5%5D%2C%5B9%5D%2C%5B6%5D%2C%5B3%5D%2C%5B4%5D%2C%5B7%5D%2C%5B1%5D%2C%5B2%5D%2C%5B8%5D%2C%5B3%5D%5D&debug=0).

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
tZyZ}:w:!+-1y^7MGn/*-X:K#S)
```

Adapted from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28375839/2586922). The general idea is to create a 2D array of the same size as the input, filled with values that increase in the same order as the zig-zag path. Then the linearized (flattened) version of that array is sorted, and the *indices* of that sorting are kept. Those are the indices that need to be applied to the input in order to produce the zig-zag path.

Input is in the form

```
[1 2 3; 5 6 4; 9 7 8; 1 2 3]
```

#### Explanation

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFp5Wn06dzohKy0xeV43TUduLyotWDpLI1Mp&input=WzEgMiAzOyA1IDYgNDsgOSA3IDg7IDEgMiAzXQ)

```
t       % input 2D array. Duplicate
ZyZ}    % get size as length-2 vector. Split into two numbers: r, c
:       % range [1,2,...,c] as a row vector
w:!     % swap, range [1;2;...;r] as a column vector
+       % add with broadcast. Gives a 2D array
-1      % push -1
y^      % duplicate previous 2D array. Compute -1 raised to that
7M      % push [1;2;...;r] again
Gn/     % divide by input matrix size, that is, r*c
*       % multiply
-       % subtract
X:      % linearize 2D array into column array
K#S     % sort and push the indices of the sorting. Gives a column vector
)       % index input matrix with that column vector
```

Answer (score 6):

## Matlab, 134 bytes

I just tried my best to shorten my code in Matlab, like telegraphing it.

```
function V=z(M)
[m,n]=size(M);
a=(1:m)'*ones(1,n);
b=ones(m,1)*(1:n);
A=a+b-1;
B=a-b;
C=(A.^2+(-1).^A.*B+1);
[~,I]=sort(C(:));
V=M(:);
V=V(I)';
```

Notes:

1. `M` is an `m×n` matrix.
2. `a` and `b` are both matrices same size of `M`, each row of `a` consists of numbers equal to its row number, while each column of `b` is equal to its column number. Thus, `a`+`b` is a matrix whose element equals to sum of its row and column number, i.e., `matrix(p,q)=p+q`.
3. Thus, `A(p,q)=p+q-1`; and `B(p,q)=p-q`.
4. `C` is mathematically stated as equation below.
   [image: Zigzagifiedly increasing matrix]
   with the equation, a zigzagifiedly increasing matrix can be made like shown below.

> ```
> C =
>      1     2     6     7
>      3     5     8    14
>      4     9    13    18
>     10    12    19    25
> ```

5. `C` indicates the order of elements of M in zigzagified results. Then, `[~,I]=sort(C(:));`returns the order, i.e., `I`, thus, `V=V(I)'` is the result.

Comment: Yes, I just found it, now I update it.

Comment: @AlexA. Thank you, Alex. For I am new to this and I wanna shorten it as short as possible but make it a snippet. Now I have fixed my code yet.

Comment: Looks good. Nice first post! :)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (SpiderMonkey 30+), 99 bytes

```
x=>[for(y of[...x,...x[0]].keys())for(z of Array(y+1).keys())if(a=x[y%2?z:y-z])if(b=a[y%2?y-z:z])b]
```

Tested in Firefox 44. Takes input as a 2D array.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 84 bytes

```python
lambda N,w,h:[N[i*w+s-i]for s in range(w+h+1)for i in range(h)[::s%2*2-1]if-1<s-i<w]
```

Porting [nimi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75609/20260). Takes a flat array with given width and height. xsot saved a byte.

---

**88 bytes:**

```python
lambda M,w,h:[M[i]for i in sorted(range(w*h),key=lambda i:(i/w+i%w,-i*(-1)**(i/w+i%w)))]
```

Takes a flat array with given width and height. Sorts the corresponding 2D coordinates `(i/w,i%w)` in zigzag order of increasing sum to get diagonals, tiebroken by either increasing or decreasing row value, based on whether the row plus column is odd or even.

Comment: That if condition can be further shortened.

Comment: @xsot Nice catch.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>79</s> <s>78</s> 73 bytes

```
(m#h)w=[m!!(y*w+x-y)|x<-[0..h+w],y<-g!!x$[0..x],y<h,x-y<w]
g=reverse:id:g
```

The input is a flat list with the number of rows and columns, e.g. `( [1,2,6,3,1,2,5,9,4,7,8,3] # 2) 6` -> `[1,2,5,9,6,3,4,7,1,2,8,3]`.

How it works: walk through the x and y coordinates of the matrix (`h` rows, `w` columns) in two nested loops:

```
  | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8    outer loop               Index is y*w+x-y, i.e.
--+------------------    x from 0 to h+w          the elements are accessed
0 | 1 2 6 3 1 2                                   in the following order:
1 | 5 9 4 7 8 3
2 |                                               1 2 4 6  8 10 
3 |                                               3 5 7 9 11 12
4 |
5 |
6 |
7 | inner loop:
8 | y from 0 to x
```

i.e. from top/right to down/left, skipping out of bound indices (`y` and `x` must satisfy `y<h` and `x-y<w`). When `x` is even, the order of the inner loop is reversed: `y` goes from `x` to `0`. I do this by picking a modifying function for the y-range `[0..x]` which is the `x`th element of `[reverse,id,reverse,id,...]`.

Edit: @xnor re-arranged the loops and saved 5 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can do `g=id:reverse:g`.

Comment: The parens on the multication `(y-x)*w` can be cut by transposing the problem: `(m#h)w=[m!!(x*w+y-x)|y<-[0..h+w],x<-g!!y$[0..y],x<h,y-x<w]
g=reverse:id:g`. Translating into Python saves 3 chars over what I had.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
Σz*İ_∂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9ziKq0jG@IfdTT9//8/OtpQx0jHWMckVifaVMdMx1zHAsiy1AGLxsYCAA)

Same idea as [Zgarb's Boustrophedonize solution.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150117/boustrophedonise/150135#comment499944_150135)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>50</s> 41 bytes

-9 Can use odometer directly

```
{(,/x)@,/((#c)#(|:;::))@'c:.=+/!#'(x;*x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJy1jksKwkAQRPd9ipIsplsHhzEfzQxCNt4gNwjkDAE/Z7d7RCGgS3fV7zVFzenKPiwy+MBcTVLxLeWURAY3pf15FzaV4yVvF7kTjYm9jwSOOOQaUQheIzS+IOrcokOTexxxyoXIWyk2aaLHSnXWoJUtejT2UFSpNmTasN2q1LgfSoguulHXfGatwte2/wub9ZjdSPQE7uY+jg==)

Comment: I just worked out that this is the same as @Razetime’s Husk solution but with fewer built-ins available.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), <s>114</s> 85 bytes

```julia
^ =size
~A=[[i%2<1?reverse(x):x for(i,x)=pairs(-A^2:A^1.|>x->diag(rotl90(A),x))]...;]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZNdT8IwFIav7a84Xph0SVncGAyoRUn8F00hC6taXYCsU6sx@@vYM74S8AO0yS76tu@zc96cPj4XJkuXyzEIa941qUdCSnMRX0XXpX7RpdXUBQMHd/OSGuYCschMaWlrNI4Ho3EUfgxda5ib7J6W86roX9JR4G8FKgxDrpY39mH@CrWMIIY2JATWqwNdSKG33fehuaFACJARg5hBh0GfQZdBm0HCIGWw0nteUYTkIODWTCtKzmSk5IANFPy6xNDTFUMLxNxXFKmjLM2PfR1bL1r5n7286T/hvm0fAt/0/o33xyB29SR8kyrfxfkvZhe7xJw6Hpgg@RB5KhNRyEUc7r9CnsTkTYG@ZQ5djtH6HFIfaaP7KNrr2TiaGRCSFcWk0rayk0VmrcZR8xKVUDsc0Fw6he8BHJgZPOk3S/MAVEAOtGa@zR36zgVQ7RZ6WulcIGF9imv1Stzevt4XNvZG1rOc4Lc62q@YkOUn)

Takes the antidiagonals (rotates and takes the main diagonals), reverses every other one, and flattens the list.

-29 bytes thanks to MarcMush:

- replace `A[end:-1:1,1:end]` with `rotl90(A)` to rotate the matrix
- rewrite with `pairs` instead of `eachindex`
- to flatten a vector of vectors `Q`, use `[Q...;]` instead of `vcat[Q...]`

Comment: [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##pZNdT8IwFIav7a84Xph0SVncGAyoRUn8F00hC6taXYCsU6sx@@vYM74S8AO0yS76tu@zc96cPj4XJkuXyzEIa941qUdCSnMRX0XXpX7RpdXUBQMHd/OSGuYCschMaWlrNI4Ho3EUfgxda5ib7J6W86roX9JR4G8FKgxDrpY39mH@CrWMIIY2JATWqwNdSKG33fehuaFACJARg5hBh0GfQZdBm0HCIGWw0nteUYTkIODWTCtKzmSk5IANFPy6xNDTFUMLxNxXFKmjLM2PfR1bL1r5n7286T/hvm0fAt/0/o33xyB29SR8kyrfxfkvZhe7xJw6Hpgg@RB5KhNRyEUc7r9CnsTkTYG@ZQ5djtH6HFIfaaP7KNrr2TiaGRCSFcWk0rayk0VmrcZR8xKVUDsc0Fw6he8BHJgZPOk3S/MAVEAOtGa@zR36zgVQ7RZ6WulcIGF9imv1Stzevt4XNvZG1rOc4Lc62q@YkOUn "Julia 0.7 – Try It Online"). It might look like a new answer but it's yours optimized

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
Þ`⁽ṘẆf
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLDnmDigb3huZjhuoZmIiwiIiwiW1sxLDIsMyw0XSxbNSw2LDcsOF0sWzksMSwyLDNdXSJd)

```
Þ`     # Antidiagonals
  ⁽ Ẇ  # To every other item
   Ṙ   # Reverse
     f # Flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 + NumPy, 122 bytes

I admit it. I worked ahead. Unfortunately, this same method cannot be easily modified to solve the other 2 related challenges...

```python
import numpy
def f(m):w=len(m);print sum([list(m[::-1,:].diagonal(i)[::(i+w+1)%2*-2+1])for i in range(-w,w+len(m[0]))],[])
```

Takes a numpy array as input. Outputs a list.

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/okHH7F)

#### Explanation:

```python
def f(m):
    w=len(m)    # the height of the matrix, (at one point I thought it was the width)
    # get the anti-diagonals of the matrix. Reverse them if odd by mapping odd to -1
    d=[list(m[::-1,:].diagonal(i)[::(i+w+1)%2*-2+1])for i in range(-w,w+len(m[0]))]
            # w+len(m[0]) accounts for the width of the matrix. Works if it's too large.
    print sum(d,[]) # join the lists
```

A lambda is the same length:

```python
import numpy
lambda m:sum([list(m[::-1,:].diagonal(i)[::(i+len(m)+1)%2*-2+1])for i in range(-len(m),len(m)+len(m[0]))],[])
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, <s>131</s> <s>118</s> <s>115</s> 107 bytes

Based on the same principe as my [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75350/49289) of [Deusovi's challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75334/49289)

I assume we can't have zero in the input matrice

```
e=enumerate
lambda s:[k for j,i in e(zip(*[([0]*n+i+[0]*len(s))for n,i in e(s)]))for k in i[::j%2*2-1]if k]
```

### Explanation

how it works :

```
            pad with 0      transpose    remove 0    reverse line           concatenate 
                                                     with even index
1 2 3       1 2 3 0 0        1 0 0        1            1                
4 5 6   --> 0 4 5 6 0    --> 2 4 0    --> 2 4     -->  2 4              -->  1 2 4 7 5 3 6 8 9
7 8 9       0 0 7 8 9        3 5 7        3 5 7        7 5 3             
                             0 6 8        6 8          6 8               
                             0 0 9        9            9
```

### Results

```
>>> [print([i,f(i)]) for i in [[[1]], [[1, 2], [3, 1]], [[1, 2, 3, 1]], [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 4], [9, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2], [5, 9, 4, 7, 8, 3]], [[1, 2, 5, 9, 6, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 3]], [[1], [2], [5], [9], [6], [3], [4], [7], [1], [2], [8], [3]]]]
# [input,                                                          output]
[[[1]],                                                            [1]]
[[[1, 2], [3, 1]],                                                 [1, 2, 3, 1]]
[[[1, 2, 3, 1]],                                                   [1, 2, 3, 1]]
[[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 4], [9, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3]],                     [1, 2, 5, 9, 6, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 3]]
[[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 1, 2, 3]],                       [1, 2, 5, 9, 6, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 3]]
[[[1, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2], [5, 9, 4, 7, 8, 3]],                         [1, 2, 5, 9, 6, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 3]]
[[[1, 2, 5, 9, 6, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 3]],                           [1, 2, 5, 9, 6, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 3]]
[[[1], [2], [5], [9], [6], [3], [4], [7], [1], [2], [8], [3]],     [1, 2, 5, 9, 6, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 3]]
```

Comment: Should `reverse even line` be `reverse odd lines` instead?

Comment: @nwp index begin at 0 ^^

Comment: Ah, you are talking about the line numbers, not the length of the line. I confused those, sorry.

Comment: @nwp np, btw I changed it to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ΣN²‰ÐOŠO<è‚
```

Inputs as `flattened_list, width, height` (even though I ignore the `height` input).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3GK/Q5seNWw4PMH/6AJ/m8MrHjXM@v8/2lDHSMdYx0THVMdMx1zHQsdSBywSy2XCZQwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JhcUpqYo5CZV1BaUmyloGRfmVBsr6SQmJeiUG57eL@SDpdSQFFqSUmlbkFRZl5JagpEKVClTmXC4S2HdgMV@JeWQISAmkP/n1vsF/GoYcPhCf5HF/jbHF7xqGHW/1qdQ9vs/0dHRxvG6gARkNYx0jEGMY1QeCYInqmOmY6JjqWOuY6FDlgkFoRgsiZgeZCcJUwWrtcMZBaQNgXKmYDVAGXNYLIgUTOwCeZgVWBZQyP80rGxAA).

**Explanation:**

The actual sorting algorithm is a direct port of [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254393/52210) for the [*Traverse a rectangle's antidiagonals* challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254367/traverse-a-rectangles-antidiagonals/). Even though the actual path over the matrix is different for both challenges, that linked challenge uses \$y,x\$ as coordinates, whereas I use \$x,y\$ here, so the actual sorting implementation is basically the exact same.

```python
Σ            # Sort the first (implicit) input-list by:
 N           #  Push the 0-based sort-index
  ²‰         #  Divmod it by the second input-width
    Ð        #  Triplicate this coordinate
     O       #  Sum the top pair together
      Š      #  Tripleswap from pair,pair,sum to sum,pair,pair
       O     #  Sum the top pair together again
        <    #  Decrease it by 1
         è   #  Modular 0-based index this sum-1 into the pair
          ‚  #  Pair it together with the other sum
             # (after which the sorted list is output implicitly)
```

Just like in my linked answer, there are a few equal-bytes alternatives for `ÐOŠO<è‚` (not as many as in the linked answer, since we don't have access to the pair as variable `y` here, since we've just created the pair manually with `N²‰`):

```python
RDODŠè‚
ÐO<è‚€O
...
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 89 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.flatMap((b,i)=>b.map((c,j)=>({c,k:++i-j/(-2)**i}))).sort((p,q)=>p.k-q.k).map(x=>x.c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLNboMwDIDvfQqOSWuCRmkLq@DY254AcUizUvGzJgVUVZr27MwO3U6MFaQosuPvizGU8iZb1RSmcy/6/dQf4l7GiRR5Lbs3aRg7QsHj5Cg@KFBQYsA@FVSvq1Xhlh5zfb5cFl@cc9HqpmPMwBVrjKjcq6i45e5xcheK9/tcN8wYR@dOukjTlywDZ97jeQ5ixIKfQbqGGQ7Lgg8EDQaYxY8bsIsNbCHAPYIdhLgP@VHvj2EDEUJrCBChOETgt6fg4RxsEUz4njJSepgXFVFB@LfvKePY0cQc/zNiZ7Y7eltcW/qyuGgOO5rn4zy0eXvPpDHjC6Uvra5PotZndsBfjvP@Gw)