# Is this a shift matrix?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, matrix, binary-matrix

A Shift matrix is a binary matrix with one superdiagonal or subdiagonal formed by only ones, everything else is a zero.
A superdiagonal/subdiagonal is a diagonal parallel to the main diagonal, which is not the main diagonal, i.e. all entries \$a_{ij}\$ where \$i=j+k\$ and \$k \neq 0\$.
The main diagonal is defined to be all entries \$a_{ij}\$ where \$i=j\$.

### Specs

- The matrix is *not* guaranteed to be square and will consist of only zeros and ones
- Take a nested list or a matrix as the input
- Output a truthy/falsy result or use two distinct values to represent truthy and falsy results
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer wins!

### Examples

```
[[1]] -> 0

[[0, 1],
 [0, 0]] -> 1

[[0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0]] -> 1

[[0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]] -> 0

[[0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1]] -> 1

[[0, 0],
 [0, 0]] -> 0

[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0]] -> 0

[[1, 1],
 [1, 1]] -> 0

[[0,1,0,0],
 [1,0,1,0],
 [0,1,0,1],
 [0,0,1,0]] -> 0

[[0,1,0],
 [1,0,0],
 [0,1,0]] -> 0

[[0,1,0],
 [0,0,1],
 [1,0,0]] -> 0

[[1,0,0],
 [0,1,0]] -> 0

[[0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [1,0,0]] -> 1

[[1,0,1],
 [0,1,0],
 [0,0,1]] -> 0

[[0,1,0],
 [1,0,0]] -> 0
```

Comment: Suggested test cases: `[[1,1],[1,1]] -> 0` and `[[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0]] -> 0`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen good point

Comment: I suggest replacing "with ones only on one superdiagonal or subdiagonal" by "with one superdiagonal or subdiagonal formed by only ones". I interpreted it incorrectly until I reached the 7th test case

Comment: Suggested test case: `[[0,1,0], [1,0,0], [0,1,0]] -> 0`

Comment: It seems to be "with one superdiagonal or subdiagonal formed by only ones _and no other ones_." from the last test case - is that correct?

Comment: Suggested testcases: `[[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0]]->0`, `[[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]->0`, `[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]]->1`, `[[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]->0`

Comment: Suggested test case: any identity matrix -> 0

Comment: I would say that your requirements would allow test case 8, 9 and 10 to be true. Nowhere you mention that the other cells need to be 0, just that (at least) one superdiagonal or subdiagonal needs to be formed by only ones

Comment: Suggested test case `[[0,1,0],[1,0,0]] -> 0` (I had a program that worked for all test cases including those in the comments above, but failed for this case.)

Comment: Are the values guaranteed to be either 0 or 1?

Comment: ty all, updated

Comment: Ah, I just noticed the word "binary" in the description.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 37 bytes

```
1=1#.([:(+./*[:*/%)/.|."1),_*<@0 1|:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/PDoIwDMbvPEVF5M/AjmJiwuIM0cST8eCVLB6MRL34Arw7FhYiJETSdFvX376vezf5QpHZLlQeBI6LQQVaQQAJpKA41wjH6/nUkKYlhqUKY5SiVEKuIok1uhQlN7ErUqBamSZyLgeEjmU000LGe5RMlqplTWyElv4LZeH9yLCV68WM8JMZpHdzHvfnh0fUUMGGw@MzcXYLb101hBIkW1aQcVi@Ze0tjZTSf0rTdukMRCMla5cNoVaChhK2SzPd6RntF/uXzRc)

*Thanks to AndrovT for catching a bug*

- `,<@0 1|:]` Append `,` items along [main diagonal](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d232.htm) (works for non-square) multiplied by infinity to...
- `([:(+./*[:*/%)/.|."1)` Product of reciprocals of every diagonal, multipled by "is there at least a single 1".  This will return 1 for all ones, infinity for partial ones, and 0 for all zeros.  To get the diagonals, we combine J's built-in for anti-diagonals `/.` with a flip about the y-axis `|."1`.
- `1#.` Sum of those catted lists
- `1=` Is the sum 1?

Comment: This doesn't work for `[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]`

Comment: @AndrovT Thanks.  Fixed but it killed the golfiness....

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒDµẒ¬ṛ¦ⱮJḊċ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a matrix of ones and zeros and yields `1` if it's a shift matrix or `0` otherwise.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJJdDWx/umnRozcOdsw8te7RxndfDHV1Huv///x8dbaCjAEWxOlwK0YaoXCDDEIzgXAMoNxYA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJJdDWx/umnRozcOdsw8te7RxndfDHV1Huv8fbn/UtOb//2iu6GjD2FgdLiBtoKNgCGQpgBgGCDEwDyRsiMQGqUVRZYhDlQF2VRAZJJsNcNiMZiyayWjGIXQbwvxiiGKLIYaJhmg@Qg4DYv0IUxULAA).

#### How?

Constructs all diagonalised representations of shift matrices of the same dimensions as the input and counts occurrences of a diagonalised version of the input.

```
ŒDµẒ¬ṛ¦ⱮJḊċ - Link: matrix of [0,1], M    e.g. [[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]]
ŒD          - diagonals (main first)           [[0,0,1],[1,1],[0],[0],[0,0]]
  µ         - start a new monadic chain - f(D=those diagonals)
   Ẓ        - is prime? (D) (used as a zero-all entries function)
        J   - (set the right argument to) range of length (D)
       Ɱ    - map with:
      ¦     -   sparse application (to elements of D)...
     ṛ      -   ...at indices: right argument (i.e. one of [1..length(D)])
    ¬       -   ...apply: logical NOT (making that single diagonal all ones)
         Ḋ  - dequeue (removing the only non-shift matrix (main diagonal one))
          ċ - count occurrences of (D)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 59 bytes

```javascript
m=>m.every((r,y)=>r.every((c,x)=>+m?x-y==m==c:c?m=x-y:1))*m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBNDoMgEIX3PQVLaFGZrQY9iHFhKDZtRBpsjJ6eWsWa1r8V883MexPeI2/yWpj78@VV@iptwa3isfJlI02HsaEd4bGZUNC2x4tKWq/jXHEuQpEo3lMIhJyVFbqqdSn9Ut9wgdMUsoyQCAUBYqf/GaMIKGIZRenndSVz5a7uu3mwNtvCD7EVgn27fgzOaP9TQBl1JwcYLwwwlmP3wGIymOUbChKtBrsICLYCWuYPhzr4TW5etm8)

Output falsy (`0`, `-0`, `NaN`) if input is not a shift matrix, output truthy (\$k\$) otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
&fyh!dt&=bd1=v
```

Outputs a [truthy or falsy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398) column array.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xy2tMkMxpUTNNinF0Lbsv716SVFpSUaleq16WmJOcaV67P9oAwUwtFYwhDEMkBlA0VgA) (includes truthy/falsy test; delete footer to see actual output). Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8F8trTJDMaVEzTYpxdC27L@9eklRaUlGpXqtelpiTnGleiyXS8j/aMNYrmgDBUNrBQMFAzATCK0VDCGUAYgBUYAiaoAsCuJCTDFAMQWuA64HrhqsyBBkqyFUqyFCvSHcZqizwOoB).

#### How it works

Consider `[0 0 0 0; 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 1 0]` as example input.

```
&f    % Implicit input. Two-output find: row and column indices of non-zeros
      % STACK: [2; 4], [1 ;3]
yh    % Duplicate from below. Concatenate horizontally
      % STACK: [2; 4], [1 2; 3 4]
!     % Transpose
      % STACK: [2; 4], [1 3; 2 4]
d     % Vertical onsecutive differences
      % STACK: [2; 4], [1 1] 
t&=   % Duplicate. All pairwise equality comparisons
      % STACK: [2; 4], [1 1], [1 1; 1 1]
bd    % Bubble up third-topmost entry. Consecutive differences
      % STACK: [1 1], [1 1; 1 1], 2
1=    % Equal to 1?, element-wise
      % STACK: [1 1], [1 1; 1 1], 0
v     % Concatenate vertically, converting to column vectors if non-matching sizes
      % STACK: [1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
ÞD₌~aḢ~AẊ₃
```

[Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnkTigox+YeG4on5B4bqK4oKDIiwiIiwiW1swLCAxXSwgWzAsIDBdXSJd) or [verify all test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiw55E4oKMfmHhuKJ+QeG6iuKCgyIsIiIsIltbMV1dXG5bWzAsIDFdLCBbMCwgMF1dXG5bWzAsIDAsIDBdLCBbMSwgMCwgMF0sIFswLCAxLCAwXV1cbltbMCwgMSwgMF0sIFsxLCAwLCAwXSwgWzAsIDAsIDBdXVxuW1swLCAxLCAwXSwgWzAsIDAsIDFdXVxuW1swLCAwXSwgWzAsIDBdXVxuW1swLCAwLCAwLCAwXSwgWzEsIDAsIDAsIDBdLCBbMCwgMCwgMCwgMF0sIFswLCAwLCAxLCAwXV1cbltbMSwgMV0sIFsxLCAxXV1cbltbMCwxLDAsMF0sIFsxLDAsMSwwXSwgWzAsMSwwLDFdLCBbMCwwLDEsMF1dIl0=).

```
ÞD         # list of all diagonals
  ₌        # apply the next two elements in parallel:
   ~a      #   filter by Any
     Ḣ     #   remove head (removes the main diagonal)
      ~A   # filter by All
           # Now the stack has the the list of diagonals that have at least one 1
             and list of all sub/superdiagonals that don't contain 0
        Ẋ  # cartesian product
         ₃ # is length equal to 1?
```

Comment: woah, nice idea

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 72 bytes

```javascript
A=>A.map((B,i)=>B.map((C,j)=>N-=i*j?A[i-1][j-1]-C&&9:i-j?C:2*C),N=1)&&!N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY67DoIwGIV3ngKXpiUtad3U/BDozsTWdCAIpg1SIsbw9hXEQUxYTs7lG46tXtVYP8zwZL27Nr4Fn0GSxfdqwDinhkCSr0FSO4eCgYlsminDhFZ2FiYROp0Ns6k8HyNJaAGCIHQo/KWECZLa9aPrmrhzN9ziiZAgKLFSQuvwazkNhaZBuBi@qT/Fsogfv@D/oNgB@S64jtsXfPPCvwE)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 29 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
εI˜d·«NFÀ]øJ2мõK€SDPsOĀ+ćÌL¢J
```

Outputs a 05AB1E truthy/falsey result (only `1` is truthy in 05AB1E): `01` if truthy; anything else (e.g. `0000`, `20`, `11`, `0100`, etc.) if falsey.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FbP03NSDm0/tNrP7XBD7OEdXkYX9hze6v2oaU2wS0Cx/5EG7SPth3t8Di3y@v8/OtpAx1DHIFYnGkgC6dj/urp5@bo5iVWVAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@mFFCUWlJSqVtQlJlXkpqikJlXUFpipaCkU@l1aLcOl5JjcklpYg5c2L7S9tBKpf/nth5ad3pOyqHth1b7uR1uiD28w8vowp7DW70fNa0Jdgko9j/SoH2k/XCPz6FFXv@V9MKU/EtLoAa42GcqKWiUFJWWZFRqKh1eDeSkJeYUpwI5tTqHttn/j46ONoyN1VGIjjbQMYzVAZIGMC6IqRNtCKWB0ggpQzQpA3QpkBDcXAMMcxHaEQYg9MGUGoJdZIgwyBBJpyHCVTCH43OhIXYXwpRA7cOiGtmLuGk0UwzhpqAFBbKzYmP/6@rm5evmJFZVAgA).

**Explanation:**

05AB1E lacks a builtin to get all (anti-)diagonals, so the first 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) of the code is to do just that..

Step 1: Get a list of all diagonals, starting with the main diagonal:

```python
ε       # Map over each row of the (implicit) input-matrix:
 I˜     #  Push the input-matrix again, and flatten it
   d    #  Transform every 0 to a 1 as well, so we have a list of 1s
    ·   #  Double each to a list of 2s
     «  #  Merge it to the current row
 NF     #  Loop the 0-based map-index amount of times:
   À    #   Rotate the row-list once towards the left
]       # Close both the inner loop and outer map
 ø      # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
  J     # Join each inner row together
   2м   # Remove all 2s in every string
     õK # Remove all empty strings from the list
  €S    # Convert each inner string back to a list of digits
```

For a matrix `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]`, the order of the list of diagonals will be `[[a,e,i],[b,f],[c],[g],[d,h]]`.

[Try just step 1 online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@mFFCUWlJSqVtQlJlXkpqikJlXUFpipaCkU@l1aLcOl5JjcklpYg5c2L7S9tBKpf/ntnqenpNyaPuh1X5uhxtiD@/wMrqw5/BW70dNa4L/K@mFKblkJqbn5yXmFIP0HF6vc2ib/f/o6GjD2FgdhehoAx3DWB0gaQDjgpg60YZQGiiNkDJEkzJAlwIJwc01wDAXoR1hAEIfTKkh2EWGCIMMkXQaIlwFczg@FxpidyFMCdQ@LKqRvYibRjPFEG4KWlAgOys29r@ubl6@bk5iVSUA)

Step 2: Check whether it's a valid Shift Matrix, so there is exactly one diagonal consisting solely of 1s without any 1s in another diagonal, and it's not the first main diagonal:

```python
D       # Duplicate the list of diagonals
 P      # Get the product of each, to check which diagonals consists solely of 1s
s       # Swap so the list of diagonals is at the top again
 OĀ     # Sum and Python-style truthify (!=0), to check which diagonals contain a 1
+       # Add the two list of checks together
ć       # Extract the head; push remainder-list and first item separately
 Ì      # Increase this first item (check of the main diagonal) by 2
  L     # Pop and push a list in the range [1,value]
   ¢    # Count for each value in this list how many times it occurs
    J   # Join these counts together
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[Try both steps online, with added debug-lines.](https://tio.run/##fVA/S8NAFN/7KY4stfQCuYIIQgnFIFiLLTqGDGdybQIxKclFjFAoLi7uLk5uUsGpKuiUdBPEz@AXie9s0pS2miF37/3@vN87P6SnDsvOpV7AOI/lYeB4nFnI8YYR30USjtvJG65ILZNH1F201biZPGSS5tCB71E3FK3P6cHHnZW8JJOj/XQ8GqWv7cbXezo9/L56PEmfmhWY4VuRyZHfR4yaNrJyuVBrPSC0vHgDKD5JDbuzsaBYFsTj/oBxmwVzEOWUOuAdJ5wPuOABNcUqNqMWqqOGmDK7Tm86miqhrWN2Rh3PYoHsgkJgoaaG1RrsuudHHg9hVwQjULBGTO5hTjfi@VO0NdUBQx5E3I5rUjqBog9vwqAY4Sx5VqvyznZ6i@GW6bpODAMjXVcwMTD8laIUV6yT/AS4hMgKpKxCorXwVdZ8S3lpUOoKKvlNREojsqQkZaoi@H8JyeaEBSWft4G9vOLf54oLWbisPMVyLMPIZNnzZZdexj8)

Comment: I believe I forgot to add the truthy/falsy result line, it's allowed.

Comment: @mathcat Thanks, modified my answer accordingly. :)

Comment: @tsh Huh.. Why thought? The [main diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal) of `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i],[j,k,l],[m,n,o],[p,q,r]]` is `[a,e,i]`, so the superdiagonal/subdiagonal are `[b,f]` and `[d,h,l]` respectively.

Comment: @tsh Nvm, I misread the 'parallel' word in the challenge as adjacent to the main diagonal.. Also, the current test cases are anything but covering in that case. :/ I'll delete and try to fix it.

Comment: @tsh Should be fixed at the cost of 11 bytes..

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>76</s> <s>69</s> 66 bytes

*Edit: -3 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
\(m)all(d<-diff(t(which(m>0,T))),d==max(dim(m)-sum(m))*sign(d[1]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMH6zGK94ozMtJLcxJKizArbpaUlaboWN51iNHI1E3NyNFJsdFMy09I0SjTKMzKTMzRy7Qx0QjQ1NXVSbG1zEys0UjJzgSp1i0tBlKZWcWZ6nkZKtGGspibEpFuMPKg2aECpZA1DTR1DHUNNTQVlBTcuXIoMgGq4ODkVFBQMdAw0dYx0jMAaQvBoAEGIFkMkNsggoAHGOsYEDTAkxgD8TkZoAvJAzoZqggTKggUQGgA)

Comment: [-3 bytes?](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMH6zGK94ozMtJLcxJKizArbpaUlaboWN51iNHI1E3NyNFJsdFMy09I0SjTKMzKTMzRy7Qx0QjQ1NXVSbG1zEys0UjJzgSp1i0tBlKZWcWZ6nkZKtGGspibEpFuMPKg2aECpZA1DTR1DHUNNTQVlBTcuXIoMgGq4ODkVFBQMdAw0dYx0jMAaQvBoAEGIFkMkNsggoAHGOsYEDTAkxgD8TkZoAvJAzoZqggTKggUQGgA)

Comment: @pajonk - I'll take 1-byte for the in-line definition of ```d```: thanks!  Swapping the sum of ```m``` for the length of ```d``` fails for some cases, unfortunately: [try it](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMH6zGK94ozMtJLcxJKizArbpaUlaboWN51iNHI1E3NyNFJsdFMy09I0SjTKMzKTMzRy7Qx0QjQ1NXVSbG1zEys0UjJzgSp1i0tBlKZWcWZ6nkZKtGGspibUpGxUCzSgVLKGgY6hnqmOARByKSCAgY4BDjGQaiwqNXVMdEw0NRWUFdy4IFYuWAChAQ)...

Comment: @pajonk - sorry - re-read the spec and see that the matrix is all zeros & ones.  Your suggestion is perfect: thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 138 bytes

```python
lambda d:any(i for i in range(-len(d)-len(d[0]),len(d)+len(d[0]))if all(d[j][k]==(j-k==i)for j in range(len(d))for k in range(len(d[0]))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY9BDoIwEEX3nGISN22kSbszJvUi2EUNVAu1EoILruAV3LDBO3kOLyBtiQjKaqZ__vv5vT_Kpj5dbNsp4LDvrrUim-fNyPMhlZBupW2QBnWpQIO2UEl7zBAxmUUpDiOhAsdBWH8ErBVIY_pHLpJCcI5yUnCusUvKx6TAebWYqT4G46HRq6y0rZFCScJEf4AVkB3QKBp1GgMTcQRuoc7jLWxm8UfnYl-7QwcI_lJsgaIT6qfO1MmW8-mk-JAWvt62Yb4B)

Comment: [120](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dU9LDoIwFNxzipe4abVN2p0hqYdgW7t4BNACFkIwkbO4YYN38hxeQH6J4mf1ZubNvM_1Vjb1sXBtl4CCfXeuE769X3I8hRFCxAJVoTvEPkFf5bEjEWXhjLQwlKKLAF1D7BrzvNdSozOjFEl5ppSlSVFBCtZBQHAk2URCOjI7MY48ZLjpxXn_o6ysq0lCtJam3wIr4DsQnvfSBQNpmAcDEINntMgPy9gcXPIND9E5BD9T8k9KLFJf5yyd8v98sTh8nja93rZTfQI)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 118 bytes

```julia
using LinearAlgebra
~A=((m,n)=size(A);X=map(i->diag(A,i),1-m:n-1);!i=sum(all.(==(i),X));A[1]<1&&!1>0&&!0==length(X)-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jU@9asMwEN79FBcCQQK76NaoCjVk7NTJEDJcW9VRkN0gycV0yKu7MnVETRIoB3fD93vHzhrCfhg6b9oank2ryZW21q@OsnOpGGvylitvvjUruaxUQydmis27oZqVueE5Fs26LZDLhVG@axhZ@8CUYhGqOJflDvePuFotcCPiFkpZ3dbhwCoeRcMTea9dgPNOAIKQ4xqPGGcPSsEHWa@zxHPaH@ikWbTN1znyRIElvPxigFv40m/h0wF5wB6hoeBMn83C5BQQXKdniJjVwKnGFe1fbS@8kYC3fYS8r/1bJuUkvzsyjL/hlHazzsUS04dRcW05/AA)

The function `~A` returns `true` if `A[1,1]` is not 1 (main diagonal check), one diagonal contains all 1's, and all but one diagonal contains all 0's. Otherwise, it returns `false`. The intermediate value `X` is a vector of all `A`'s diagonals, and the intermediate function `!i` determines if all elements in a diagonal equal the value `i`.

Note: As in [a somewhat related answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253819/114865), `LinearAlgebra` is imported only for the function `diag(A,k)`, which returns the `k`th diagonal of A. If the diagonal `k` doesn't exist, no error results, but an empty set is returned. If these are filtered out, the bounds don't need to be specified precisely; using the range `-9:9` would work for all test cases and eliminate the need for calculating `size(A)`.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 139 bytes

```php
fn($m)=>$m[0][0]?!1:(count($f=array_merge(...array_map(fn($v)=>array_keys($v,1),$m)))>1?$f==range(min($f),max($f)):end($m)[0]||end($m[0]));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLdaoMwFL73Kc7AiwSCNbd11geRUEKb1LHFhkTLyrpndydqa9dmAyHnO@f7ORptY4fXyjY2SdJO@c5DCXUCUNdcCAarFWj54VUytnIGXLBQYpXP8871y3jsBwbU/BcK0j80/B/NXc7DHo80Hl3njhK1ia78tMFTVtSOX78OTGUkj7OcLWEjvhmP@IammVgcRIE3FG5n0C1JDS03qalzgU/1wtdkd@zbjqS6lM7J89Yod1Aky7IZSkuC7ISyqfOuzh4x45ShGaUbXqG4dLJFnXlDrqbMyM9w0rVq9yETwy6XqcaS0mLQR6fkrgEy/zzSA/LgC9/iJN123xtLUh@0tEi@hx8)

**Ungolfed**

```php
fn($m) => 
  $m[0][0] ? !1 :
  (count($f = array_merge(...array_map(fn($v) => array_keys($v, 1), $m))) > 1
  ? $f == range(min($f), max($f))
  : end($m)[0] || end($m[0]));
```

Comment: I'm not very good at PHP, but this looks cool

Comment: You have an extra space after `?`

Comment: `[[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]` should be falsy.

Comment: Fixed the main diagonal being considered a true case

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔ΣＥυ⁻⌕Ａι1κθ¿⌈θ¿⁼⌈θ⌊θ¬№ΣＥυ⁻⌕Ａι0κ⌈θ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjfPl2dk5qQqaHjmFZSWBJcUZeala2hqKgSUFmdolOooZGpaczkWF2em52kEl-Zq-CYWgER9M_NKizXcMvNSHHNyNDJ1FJQMlTR1FLI1NYFkIVBLZpoCUG1FZi5QTyHQOBDftbA0MacYSRhsDkwJ0Eqg3SUafvklGs75pUAWXvsMEPYh2aOpab2kOCm5GOq55dFKumU5SrFrDAwMuAyB2MDQgAsiBQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated binary strings and outputs a Charcoal boolean i.e. `-` for a shift matrix, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Input the matrix.

```
≔ΣＥυ⁻⌕Ａι1κθ
```

Find the diagonals of all of the `1`s in the matrix.

```
¿⌈θ
```

If there is at least one `1` not on the main diagonal*, and ...

```
¿⁼⌈θ⌊θ
```

... if all of the `1`s are on the same diagonal, ...

```
¬№ΣＥυ⁻⌕Ａι0κ⌈θ
```

... check whether there are any `0`s on that diagonal.

*Strictly speaking this tests that either at least one `1` is above the diagonal or there are `1`s that are only below the diagonal.