# Count the word from matrix

Tags: code-golf, matrix

## BackStory

Given a square matrix of alphabets which contain English letters in arbitrary manner. While searching a word in it, you can go left to right horizontally, vertically downwards or diagonally towards left (both upwards and downwards).

You have to find the `number of matches of a given word` in the matrix.

For example, In the given square matrix `{A#A#K,A#S#K,A#K#K}`,[image]

The word `"ASK`"  is matched four times in the input matrix. So the output will be 4.

## Input Format

You will be given two-dimensional string array and a string(Word to be searched) as arguments.

## Output Format

You need to return the Number of occurrences of the word in the matrix {an integer}.

## Sample Test Case1

Sample Input

```
2
2
A S
S T

AS
```

## Sample Output

2

## Sample Test Case 2

```
Sample Input
5
5
E D E E E
D I S K E
E S E E E
E C E E E
E E E E E

DISK
```

## Sample Output

1

## Explanation:

In this example, "`DISK`"  is matched only one time in the input matrix. So the output will be `1`.

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37940/42963), but not quite a duplicate.

Comment: `You will be given a function which contains` -> what does that mean? Would getting input in a different format be acceptable?

Comment: Yep... @Arnauld

Comment: The input format is specified clearly.@StepHen

Comment: If `KSID` is in the matrix, does it count as an occurrence of `DISK`?

Comment: No .@EriktheOutgolfer...........

Comment: This appears to be copied from elsewhere, without attribution. I'll put this on hold until you add one.