# Word Search Solver

Tags: code-golf, string, word-search

I got to wondering yesterday if I could write a program to comb through a given word search and output the answers. It was actually surprisingly easy. Now I wonder just how small we can get.

## Rules

- Your first input is a string or collection of n lines, each of which is n characters long
- Your second input is a list of words in any format to find in the puzzle
- All words in the search list are guaranteed to be in the puzzle
- Words can be oriented in any of the four cardinal directions, as well as diagonally both forwards and backwards
- Only uppercase A-Z characters will be present in the puzzle
- Your code must find every word in the the search string, and output the coordinate position of the starting letter, where 0,0 is the top left character.
- In the event that you locate more than one instance of the same word, you may handle it however you like. Output it multiple times, or only once, it's up to you

## Examples/Test Cases

Given the following board:

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP
```

And the following search string:

```
ABCD,CGKO,POMN,NJF,AFKP,CFI,LGB,MJGD
```

Your program should output the following, in any order:

```
ABCD at 0,0
CGKO at 0,2
PONM at 3,3
NJF at 3,1
AFKP at 0,0
CFI at 0,2
LGB at 2,3
MJGD at 3,0
```

As always, shortest answer wins

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first challenge!

Comment: [Similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37940/31625), the only real difference seem to be the inclusion of the location in the output.

Comment: @NL628 Yes, all search words are guaranteed to be in the puzzle. If there is more than one occurence, you can either output it both times or ignore it the second, it's up to you.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Great idea. I will update it as you suggested.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Yes it should :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I addressed this seconds before you posted your question, but yes, every word is guaranteed to be present, and you may output any coordinate you wish, as many as you want.

Comment: Will letters appear on the board more than once?

Comment: @Oliver They definitely could. The example is just that - an example. The algorithm should be able to solve any word search

Comment: Can the coordinates be 1-indexed?

Comment: Can I take the input as a function parameter? Do I have to read it from stdin?

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>154</strike> <strike>152</strike> <strike>150</strike> 141 bytes

- thanks to Arnauld for reducing by 2 bytes

returns array of locations (it was a string with new lines before)

```javascript
(b,w)=>w.map(s=>[...b].map((_,p)=>[1,-1,r=b.search`
`,-r,~r,++r,-~r,~r].map(d=>[...s].every((c,i)=>c==b[p+d*i])?s+=" at "+[p/r|0,p%r]:0))&&s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5db4IwFIbv@ysMyUw7Dh3o3ZK6KA4GKnBPyMqXG8ZB0xLNksW/zqhku3t6@p7nPaf8kqtSNqK32q6qhyMbcAFXwlZX@pULrNgqpZQW2f2F30GMX6kDlgOSFVTVuSw/OeJgSbhJME0J1k3jtFBN6yqj9aWW3xiX0IyCkrEiFWb12GTkRZnMmOX9zDBT8SR/bBAPMnu2CZnPFRnKrlXduabn7gMfMV9v3C169fw3FIS7PTpEccLB0FNw/V0MSRwdIAo9WHu7BFwvgL2/gUPobw2qxLnpOXBCT13TjkczdvfpchtspAUTL5D2aF7CEo26CR2krf9xL/hLjx0aF2NYV01pm5PhFw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 213 bytes

```python
lambda a,W:[(w,i,j)for w in W for i in R(L(a))for j in R(L(a[0]))for U in R(9)if U-4and g(i,j,U/3-1,U%3-1,a).find(w)==0]
g=lambda i,j,u,v,a,s='':L(a)>i>=0<=j<L(a[0])and g(i+u,j+v,u,v,a,s+a[i][j])or s
L=len;R=range
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU5Nc4IwFLznV@TSSTI8rf241BpnFAtFEa2W8YAc0uGjYWxwAGX66ylR7OXNvt19u@/4W33n6rFJ@L45iJ@vSGABu2FAa5CQsSQvcI2lwjusodRwQ10q2EXK/vdgEF4p/0q9MJlgv/csVIRT2kaBf//UewD/Tk/B@olUEa0Z54MQpbyr1r4TnEFAyQkZ6p6xHPPBiGejrqQLNE6QGeeb2RCBDIMsZO0DJXL5IVavG14IlcZNFZdVXGCOCSGTqTlDb5b9jpz5wkVLb7VGH5vtZyv1y@NBVpShOi@iUtu1GUx7sYL1yluCN7dgYi3WYFoOuPYU2gRYzu0ZbD3ndk6AMHQspKow2SvSz3Kp6PWDG590O1yKWPMH)

`g` takes a starting location `i,j` and a direction `u,v` and via recursion extracts the string starting at that location in that direction.

`f` then visits each starting location `i,j` and direction `U/3-1,U%3-1` and checks each word `w` to see if the resulting string starts with `w`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>149</s> 147 bytes

```python
def g(b,w):h=b.find('\n')+1;return[f'{y} at {i//h},{i%h}'for y in w for i in range(len(b))for d in(1,h+1,h,h-1,-1,~h,-h,1-h)if y==b[i::d][:len(y)]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1Bi4MwFITv@RWhsCShT4vszcVDa1e3Wqt310MlagIlSswiIu5fd@PCPBg@ZuYNsxG9et823rS4ozVMzBdB7bZScUq@FWFH70M35kersiXLvOKnwYs8ncQKi3wTK2l7jWcsFZ7wbuVu9VN1DX01itaM7ZRbSj0QR3sgHA@sfgU4AjxHMNniOQjqUvo@r0p/782sqrZOS44DTAhB50t4RZ9R/IVuSXpH2SMvkOXuaLQcKENo6jUfbfiwJyGM0xyK/JHBI4ngHKUFhNEN7vEFsiS@HtxxeElDCRBbHbRUhnZ0fwf4f4ix7Q8)

#### Ungolfed version

```python
def g(b,w):
    h = b.find('\n') + 1                              # width of a row plus the '\n'
    a = []
    for y in w:                                       # iterate over the words
        for i in range(len(b)):                       #   iterate over the game board
            for d in(1,h+1,h,h-1,-1,~h,-h,1-h):       #     for each possible direction
                if y==b[i::d][:len(y)]:               #       see if the word matches
                    a.append(f'{y} at {i//h},{i%h}')
    return a
```

The main idea is that `b[i::d]` selects a slice from the game board.  The slice starts as position `i` and extends in the direction `d`.  For example, `d = h+1` corresponds to the southeast diagonal, whereas `d = ~h`, which is the same as `-h-1`, corresponds to the northwest diagonal.  `[:len(y)]`  chops the slice off at the same length as the word being searched.