# Word Search on a Torus

Tags: code-golf, string, grid

## The Challenge

Given a list of words and a grid of letters, your job is to determine which of the given words can be found on the grid in all 8 directions (forward, backward, up, down, and the 4 diagonal directions), much like a word search. The grid is toroidal, so the grid wraps around on the edges. Letters can be reused with this wrap-around property.

Wrapping around for diagonals behaves as you might expect. On a 4x6 grid going diagonally down and right, you would expect movement to look like this:

```
9 . 5 . 1 .
. . . 6 . 2
3 . . . 7 .
. 4 . . . 8
```

For an example of a wrap-around reuse word:

```
S E A H O R
```

Would be able to make SEAHORSE

## Example Test Cases

Given this grid and the word list [ANT, COW, PIG]:

```
A N T
W C O
P G I
```

The result would be [ANT, COW, PIG]

---

Given this grid and the word list [CAT, DOG, DUCK, GOOSE, PUMPKIN]:

```
N O O D M E
O I O C U U
P G K O T C
K A U P S K
```

The result would be [DOG, DUCK, PUMPKIN]

---

Given this grid and the word list [TACO, BEEF, PORK]:

```
T A C B
A P O R
K E E F
B F C P
```

The result would be an empty list

---

Given this grid and the word list [ACHE, ASK, BAD, BOOK, COOK, CROW, GAS, GOOD, LESS, MARK, MASK, MEAL, SAME, SEAHORSE, SELL, SHOW, SLACK, WOOD]:

```
G S L A C K 
H A E S R O
C M S K O O
A K S D W B
```

The result would be [ASK, BOOK, COOK, CROW, GAS, GOOD, LESS, MASK, SEAHORSE, SHOW, SLACK]

---

Given this grid and a [list of all English words](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt) that are at least 3 letters long:

```
A R T U P
N T U B O
E S R O H
Q E T I U
E A T D P
```

The result would be [AEQ, AES, ANE, ART, ARTS, ATRIP, BOID, BON, BREE, BUD, BUT, DUB, DUE, DUET, EAN, EAR, EAT, EER, EST, HES, HIT, HOP, HOR, HORS, HORSE, HUP, NAE, NOB, NOBUT, ONT, OOT, OPP, ORS, OUR, OUT, PAR, PART, PAT, PEA, PEAT, PEE, PEER, PIR, POH, PUT, QAT, QUI, QUIT, QUITE, RAP, REE, RIP, RIPA, RTI, RUT, SEA, SEAR, STD, STR, STRA, STRAE, SUU, TAA, TAE, TAP, TAPIR, TEE, TIU, TOO, TRA, TRAP, TRI, TRIP, TUB, TUP, TUR, UDI, UIT, URE, UTE]

## Rules

- No exploiting standard loopholes
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins
- Input and output may be in any convenient format
- You may assume that both the grid and the words list will use only capital letters
- The output order of the words does not matter
- You do not have to, but may, filter out duplicates

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162956/word-search-solver).

Comment: @Lynn Even though I can think of one other approach, I agree, it too reduces to WSP.

Comment: Where were all of you when this was in the sandbox? Just saying. It got 3 upvotes there.

Comment: This is clearly not a duplicate. Although being on a torus doesn't sound like much of a change, most implementations will be significantly different. Here's my Python 3 approach anyway `lambda s,d:[w for w in d if any(r(s,w,x,y,i,j)for x in range(l(s[0]))for y in range(l(s))for i in[-1,0,1]for j in[-1,0,1]if i*i+j*j)];r=lambda s,w,x,y,i,j:w==""or s[y%l(s)][x%l(s[0])]==w[0]and r(s,w[1:],x+i,y+j,i,j);l=len`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Lẋ@Zɗ⁺ZU$3Ð¡;ŒD$€Ẏw€⁸ẸðÐf
```

A dyadic link accepting a list of lists of characters (the words) on the left and a list of lists of characters (the rows of the grid) on the right which returns a list of list of characters (the found words).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/n4a5uh6iT0x817ooKVTE@POHQQuujk1xUHjWtebirrxxIPWrc8XDXjsMbDk9I@394uff//9FKjs4erko6So7B3kDSydEFRPr7gzjOUCrIPxxIuTsGg0h/f5AKH9dgEM/XMcgbTIE1@7o6@gCpYEdfkIHBro4e/kHBEKYPWMIDbFCwj6MzSHk4yKhYoAvcoSJcCkoejq7BQf5gprNvsLc/hOnoHewS7qQUCwA)**

#### How?

Filters the words by their existence in the grid tiled to be word-length times as wide and word-length times as high:

```
Lẋ@Zɗ⁺ZU$3Ð¡;ŒD$€Ẏw€⁸ẸðÐf - Link: words, grid
                       Ðf - filter (the words) keeping those for which
                      ð   - ...the dyadic link to the left ...is truthy:
     ⁺                    -   perform this twice:
    ɗ                     -     last three links as a dyad:
L                         -       length (of the current word)
 ẋ@                       -       repeat (the rows) by (that number)
   Z                      -       transpose (making the rows become the columns)
         3Ð¡              -   repeat three times and collect the results (inc input):
        $                 -     last two links as a monad:
      Z                   -       transpose
       U                  -       upend     (together these rotate by a quarter)
                €         -   for €ach:
               $          -     last two links as a monad:
             ŒD           -       get forward-diagonals
            ;             -       concatenate
                 Ẏ        -   tighten (to get all the runs across the grid)
                    ⁸     -   chain's left argument (the word)
                   €      -   for €ach run:
                  w       -     sublist-index (0 if not found)
                     Ẹ    -   any truthy? (i.e. was the word found?)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>269</strike> <strike>214</strike> <strike>164</strike> 163  bytes

-50 bytes with the golfing I learned since last year.
-1 byte thanks to Redwolf Programs

```javascript
l=>g=>l.filter(w=>g.some((r,y)=>r.some((c,x,r,z=[-1,0,1],m=(a,b,c=b.length)=>(a%c+c)%c)=>z.some(l=>z.some(p=>[...w].every((h,i)=>h==g[m(l*i+y,g)][m(p*i+x,r)]))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDRisIwEHz3Kw5Bmp5rOD8ghViLhbYEmgcfQh5qLtYe0UoVPf15b9MLd4HZmd2ZbCBfza25mKE7Xxen/tO@9uzlWNKyxNF95652IHds6aU/WkIGeMQsGUJn4BsGeDK1WMIHLDUcGWlgB4btqLOn9nrAMGlmZm7imUH9/L3o/tSZJYpSetfU3uzwIOQAHeYOjLXqSNx7N39AG2vUZ9T4Wqzj8bxMf7r0zlLXt2RP1JSneTaFKZcF1hVf@yqEb9JAtdgibbj0VQifKDPpu4rXxUjj5SrjJZLklV8oM56LWv7KcjTycZEseerjW79KxxOiVLSJIJKIEsERKaKINEzeVJSHWRYyNUIEz@eqMC/G@b/Hw8x7a8QWsYq0nuAn/AA)

old 214 bytes version:

```javascript
(l,g)=>l.filter(w=>g.some((r,y)=>r.some((c,x,r,e=w.split``,m=(a,b)=>((a%b)+b)%b)=>[[0,1],[0,-1],[1,0],[-1,0],[1,1],[1,-1],[-1,1],[-1,-1]].some(v=>e.every((h,i)=>h==g[m(v[0]*i+y,g.length)][m(v[1]*i+x,r.length)])))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDbioMwEH3vVyyFYtyOUj8gQmqlgkrAPPQhCLXd1LrYWlTs9uu7kxh2hTPHc3ES/K6majj3zWP07t2Xel/om7RQuzRs/UvTjqonTxrW/tDdFCE9vDDprTrDD/Sg6NMfHm0zHo9wo6SCE1YIqVYnd31yV1pJuYGgBJyepgA2OL2ZApgtk3iz8ows52MmGipfTap/EXKFBtddKa3ljUxyU3426xfUfqvu9Xh1S@MG2sWb/bmuft7n7j50rfLbriYXIpcsSuIlLJlIcW7ZTk/OtYgsFfyAtGdCT851I4uFVjkrUkPm4zxmGZJguV4oYpbwQsyvmQkSs0hkLNL1g15VwkJKZ@@AIxAZgiEiROpg9iGdxHqx7RQIbjPdy62fGv8/Y9bT2Q5xQGydslzgP/gF)

Semi readable versoin:

```javascript
(l, g) =>
    l.filter(w =>
        g.some((r, y) => //loop through rows
            r.some((c, x, r, e = w.split``, //loop through columns and split word in chars
                m = (a, b) => ((a % b) + b) % b) //modulo function which also works for negative
                =>
                [[0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0], [1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, 1], [-1, -1]].some(v => //the different directions
                    e.every((h, i)
                        => h == g[m(v[0] * i + y, g.length)][m(v[1] * i + x, r.length)]
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: -1 byte: replace `(l,g)=>` with `l=>g=>`, and input is taken as `(l)(g)`

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Thanks, I changed it. Not sure how to cut off more bytes

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, <s>203</s> 180 bytes

```
#(let[C count R range h(C %)w(C(% 0))](for[Q %2[y x][[1 0][0 1][-1 0][0 -1][1 1][1 -1][-1 -1][-1 1]]r(R h)c(R w):when(=(for[i(R(C Q))]((%(mod(+(* y i)r)h))(mod(+(* x i)c)w)))Q)]Q))
```

The grid must be a vector of vector of characters and the word list must be a sequence of sequence of characters. Sorry, no strings ;)